# How to explain about difference of the one figure in the paper with other figures

Tags: sentence-construction

We have three Figures, Fig. 1, Fig. 2, Fig. 3

I intend to imply :

In Fig. 2, we have more details and it has better resolution which let us judge about the content more accurately; this judgment is a roughly hard task if we use Fig.1 or Fig. 3.

I have written down:

> Fig. 2 provide close observations that we cannot have in Fig. 1 and Fig. 3.

---

Q1 : Is my sentence correct ?

Q2: Is there any better substitution ?

Comment: If you're looking for a phrase to describe Fig. 2, I'd suggest *higher fidelity.*

Comment: What should I say ? It gives higher fidelity ? It provides higher fidelity ? or ... ?

Comment: The figure would *have* higher fidelity, or *be* a higher fidelity - e.g. "Fig. 2's higher fidelity allows us to make observations not afforded otherwise."

Comment: There are hundreds of ways to say this, but I personally would use something like, "Figure 2 allows closer examination of the content due to its greater detail and better resolution, as compared to figures 1 and 3."

Comment: Are Fig1, Fig2, and Fig3 the same picture just different resolutions, or is Fig1 and Fig3 zoomed out, or are Fig1 and Fig3 different areas of Fig2?

Answer (score 1):

> In Fig. 2, we have more details and it has better resolution which let us judge about the content more accurately; this judgment is a roughly hard task if we use Fig.1 or Fig. 3.

You can say exactly that, followed by the conclusions that the differences allow you to make.  Something like

> Fig. 2, having better resolution and more detail than Fig. 1 and Fig. 3, allows us to make observations not afforded otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

To stick with your example as much as possible,

> Fig. 2 *provides* **close-up** observations that **are difficult to see** in Fig. 1 and Fig. 3.